# Completely decouple Android ViewModel implementation from Composable with Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Currently, I have something similar to:

```
interface MyViewModel {
    val elements: StateFlow<List<MyElements>>
    val visible: StateFlow<Boolean>

    fun onClick(button: MyElement)
}

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModelImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val myUseCases: MyUseCases,
) : ViewModel(), MyViewModel {

    override val elements: StateFlow<List<MyElements>> = myUseCases.getList()
    override val visible: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> by lazy { MutableStateFlow(false) }

    override fun onClick(button: MyElement) {
        myUseCases.click(button)
        ...
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    myViewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModels<MyViewModelImpl>(),
) { ... }
```

I would like to know if there is some way to completely decouple my Composable from my ViewModel implementation class (i.e. remove the `<MyViewModelImpl>` in `hiltViewModels()`). I've tried a few different things, such as making the interface an abstract class and creating `@Binds` and `@Provides` methods in Dagger Hilt `@Module`s, but I can't seem to get it right. Ideally, the Composable should have no knowledge of the implementing ViewModel class so that I can change it for testing etc. This would be a big help because I have several composables that inject the same ViewModel interfaces.

Comment: "so that I can change it for testing etc." - you already have that ability, just by passing in some other value for `myViewModel` that implements your interface.

Comment: Ahaha, I completely missed that. Good point! I'm sure there are other situations where I might want to switch it out for something else though?